# Convex Function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$f: U\subset\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function if $f(tx+(1-t)y)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$, for all $x,y \in U$ and all $t \in [0,1]$.

If $f$ is convex and continuous function, and $f$ has partial derivatives at every points of $U$, show that $f$ it is class $C^1$.

I tried to prove, what the partial derivative of each f the coordinated function was continuous, but I could not. Somebody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "UCR"?

Comment: Its U contained in R^m. Sorry about, I written without LaTex.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now.

Comment: I suppose $U$ is an open set? Otherwise, the partial derivatives need not be defined.

Comment: Yes, $U$ is an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there must be a nicer way to prove this, but here's my quick go.

Without loss of generality, assume that the origin $O\in U$ with $f(O)=0$ and $\partial f/\partial x_i(O)=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,m$ (i.e. $\nabla f(O)=0$). Otherwise, for any $x\in U$, let $g(w)=f(x+w)-w\cdot\nabla f(x)$, and we get $g(O)=0$ and $\nabla g(O)=0$, and the proof applies to $g$ instead.

Because of convexity, this makes $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$. Otherwise, if say $f(a)<0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$, we get $f(ta)\le tf(a)$ which makes $a\cdot\nabla f(O)\le f(a)<0$.

Next, assume that the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x_r$ is discontinuous at $O$ for some $r$. That means there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that either $\partial f/\partial x_r>\epsilon$ or $\partial f/\partial x_r<-\epsilon$ for points arbitrarily close to $O$.

Assume it is the former: $\partial f/\partial x_r>\epsilon$ for points arbitrarily close to $O$. (Proof for the other case is similar.) Let $u_1,u_2,\ldots\in\mathbb{R}^m$ be a sequence of such points with $\partial f/\partial x_r(u_i)>\epsilon$ that converges towards $O$.

If $\partial f/\partial x_r(u)>\epsilon$ for some $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $e_r$ denotes the $r$th unit vector, then
$$
f(u+te_r)
\ge f(u)+t\cdot\partial f/\partial x_r(u)
\ge f(u)+t\epsilon
\text{ for all }t.
$$
Plug in $u=u_i$ and take the limit, which we can as $f$ is continuous, giving $f(te_r)\ge t\epsilon$. This in turn implies that $\partial f/\partial x_r(O)\ge\epsilon$, which contradicts the assumption that this should be zero.

Some of these steps require that $f$ be defined in a neighbourhood of $O$: e.g., on an open ball: in particular the argument for the last limit.

Comment: Can you show me how can you assume that $\nabla f(0)=0$, please?

Comment: If $\nabla f(0)=a$, replace $f$ by $g(x)=f(x)-a\cdot x$, and perform the proof for $g$ instead which does have $\nabla g(0)=0$.

Comment: Clear, thank you. Then your proof looks OK to me.

Comment: Perfect. Just one question that I dont understand. Why $f(ta)≤tf(a)$ implies that $a⋅∇f(O)≤f(a)<0$?

Comment: @LetDC: Since the derivatives exist, we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} f(ta)/t=a\cdot\nabla f(a)$. Since $f(ta)/t\le f(a)$ for all $t$, this must also be the case for the limit. The same argument is used later for $f(te_r)\ge t\epsilon$.

Comment: @LetDC: I guess I should have specified in the above comment that, in taking the limit of $f(ta)/t$, we keep $t>0$ and take the limit $t\rightarrow 0^+$. The convexity expression $f(ta)\le tf(a)+(1-t)f(O)$ is for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @EinarRødland Your explanation was exellent! Thanks.

Comment: @EinarRødland I was see this question again, and I have a doubt. Can you help me again?

Comment: @LetDC: What's the doubt/question?

Comment: @EinarRødland Can you explain better, why $\nabla f(0)=0$? I know that you already answered this question, but I do not quite understand. Thanks.

Comment: @LetDC: I've added a line in the answer on why we may assume $\nabla f(0)=0$ without loss of generality: i.e., how the proof applies also when $\nabla f(0)\not=0$.

Comment: @LetDC: The alternative is to rewrite the proof without this simplification: i.e., around $f(x_0)$ we have $f(x_0+z)\ge f(x_0)+z\cdot\nabla f(x_0)$, and so on. The whole proof will be exactly the same, except the linear term $z\cdot\nabla f(x_0)$ is used as the lower bound throughout instead of $0$.